# Pass multiple lines in a variable

Tags: python, variables

How would I pass variable "tabbing" from NewsTabs.py to GUI.py and have it run in GUI.py

**GUI.py**

```
from Tkinter import *
from notebook import *
import NewsFeed
import NewsTabs

root = Tk()
n = notebook(root, TOP)

f1 = Frame(n())

NewsTabs.Tabs

f2 = Frame(n())
lable1 = Label(f2, text="Pre Alpha! \n Version 0.0.0.1 \n Fourms not yet implemented")
lable1.grid(row=1,column=1)

n.add_screen(f1, "News")
n.add_screen(f2, "Fourms")

frame = Frame(width=max, height=max, bg="white")
frame.pack()
root.title('RazeTheWorld')

root.mainloop()
```

**NewsTabs.py**

```
Tabbing = {
w = Button(f1, text="Main", bd=0, bg="white")
w.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky = W)
w1 = Button(f1, text="News", bd=0, bg="white")
w1.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky = W)
w2 = Button(f1, text="VideoReview", bd=0, bg="white")
w2.grid(row=2,column=1, sticky = W)
w3 = Button(f1, text="VideoNews", bd=0, bg="white")
w3.grid(row=3,column=1, sticky = W)
w4 = Button(f1, text="VideoGameplay", bd=0, bg="white")
w4.grid(row=4,column=1, sticky = W)
w5 = Button(f1, text="Hardware", bd=0, bg="white")
w5.grid(row=5,column=1, sticky = W)
w6 = Button(f1, text="CPU", bd=0, bg="white")
w6.grid(row=6,column=1, sticky = W)
w7 = Button(f1, text="Grapics", bd=0, bg="white")
w7.grid(row=7,column=1, sticky = W)
}

def Tabs():
    return Tabbing
```

Answer (score 0):

In any other source file (in your case, probably GUI.py):

```
import NewsTabs

tabs = NewsTabs.Tabs()
```

or:

```
import NewsTabs
tabs = NewsTabs.tabbing
```

The first would be useful if NewsTab does *not* have a constant value.

Be aware that your variable `Tabbing` is not valid Python. You need to take all of the code inside the curly braces and put it outside; then, you want to make a list of the objects you created:

```
tabbing = [w, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7]
```

Comment: in NewsTabs I get this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manraj\Desktop\RTWPROJECT0.0.0.1\NewsTabs.py", line 3, in <module>
    Tabbing = w = Button(f1, text="Main", bd=0, bg="white")
NameError: name 'Button' is not defined

Comment: @Freeloader that's because you never imported Tkinter into GUI.py. Be aware that the whole thing is not valid Python. I explain why in my answer.